# Problemas com versão mobile no meu site

Tags: css, html5

estou desenvolvendo um site para um amigo e não estou conseguindo criar a versão mobile do mesmo.

Quando tento verificar a versão mobile do site com a ajuda da ferramenta inspecionar do google chrome ele fica completamente desalinhado apesar de ja ter configurado o widht com 100%. Segue a imagem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até a FLEXBOX fica bugada, mas era para ela acompanhar o layout da página.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Vou enviar o codigo abaixo sem as imagens:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700&display=swap');

/* Resetando configurações do Navegador Padrão */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.whatsapp {
  position: fixed;
  top: 82%;
  left: 1%;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 110px;
}


/* INICIO DO CABEÇALHO */

#cabecalho {
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ff7f00, #ff7f00, #fed728, #fedd34, #fee23f);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#logotipo {
  height: 90px;
  width: 156px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  background: url(../img/logo.png);
  background-size: cover;
}

#content_cabecalho {
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  width: 350px;
  font-size: 23px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#main_menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ff7f00, #ff7f00, #fed728, #fedd34, #fee23f);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menuitem {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

.menuitem a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* FIM DO CABEÇALHO */

#content {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  height: 150px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.item img {
  border-radius: 17px;
}

.tituloproduto {
  margin: -130px 10px -10px 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 280px;
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.descricaoproduto {
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  width: 280px;
}

.botaocomprar {
  margin: -5px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 280px;
  position: relative;
  left: 210px;
}

.botaocomprar button {
  color: white;
  background-color: #ffcc00;
  width: 170px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-color: #ffcc00;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.botaocomprar button:hover {
  background-color: #c72c2c;
  border: 1px solid #c72c2c;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}


/* Menu 2 */

#main_plans {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), linear-gradient(to right, #ff7f00, #ff7f00, #fed728, #fedd34, #fee23f);
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#content_plans {
  min-height: 20px;
}

.botaocategorias {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
}

.botaocategorias button {
  color: white;
  background-color: #ffcc00;
  width: 170px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-color: #ffcc00;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#fundoimagem1 {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), url(../img/21.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}

#fundoimagem1 h1 {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 100px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#fundoimagem1 h2 {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 0px;
  font-size: 60px;
  animation: blinker 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}


/* FIM DO MENU 2*/

#frasedeentrada {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 70px;
  left: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 41px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 6px 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#frasedeentrada i {
  position: relative;
  left: 250px;
  top: 120px;
  animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

#imagemx i {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 6px 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}


/* Fim do Menu 2 */


/* Banner e Botões */

#botaodiario {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 170px;
  background-color: #ffcc00;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #000;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #000000;
  padding-top: -20px;
  border-bottom: 0px;
}

#botaodiario:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 233, 36);
  border-color: rgb(241, 230, 123);
  transition: background-color .5s;
}

#botaosemanal {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 170px;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: #ffcc00;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #000;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #000000;
  border-bottom: 0px;
}

#botaosemanal:hover {
  background-color: rgb(241, 230, 123);
  border-color: rgb(241, 230, 123);
  color: black;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}

#botaomensal {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 170px;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: #ffcc00;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #000;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #000000;
  border-bottom: 0px;
}

#botaomensal:hover {
  background-color: rgb(241, 230, 123);
  border-color: rgb(241, 230, 123);
  color: black;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}


/* Fim do Banner e Botões */

#comocomprar {
  font-size: 19px;
}


/* INICIO DOS PRODUTOS */

#background1 {
  background-color: #ffcc00;
}

#produtos_ovo {
  font-size: 13px;
}

#zoomprodutos {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#zoomprodutos a {
  color: black;
}

#zoomprodutos a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#zoomprodutos img {
  max-width: 100%;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#zoomprodutos:hover img {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* FIM DOS PRODUTOS */

footer {
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#colunafinal {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

.dark-line {
  font-size: 11px;
  background-color: rgb(59, 59, 59);
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 0 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  #content {
    height: 300px;
  }
  #main_menu {
    height: 50px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1087px) {
  #main_plans {
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 450px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Ovos 24 Horas | Compre Online</title>

  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6e07d76513.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Indie+Flower&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./img/android-chrome-512x512.png">

</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div id="cabecalho">

      <div id="logotipo">
      </div>

      <div id="content_cabecalho">
        <h5>atendimento@ovo24horas.com.br<br/></h5>
        (11) 2222-3333 | 9.4444-2222
      </div>

    </div>
  </header>


  <nav id="main_menu">
    <div class="menuitem"><a href="index.php"> Home <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a></div>
    <div class="menuitem"><a href="#">Planos <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i> </a></div>
    <div class="menuitem"><a href="tiposdeovos.php">Tipos de Ovos <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a></div>
    <div class="menuitem"><a href="cidades.php">Cidades que Atendemos</a></div>
    <div class="menuitem"><a href="faleconosco.php">Contato</a></div>
  </nav>


  <div id="fundoimagem1">
    <div class="container">

      <h1 class="text-center">RECEBA EM SUA CASA</h1>
      <h2 class="text-center">OVOS DA MELHOR QUALIDADE</h2>
      <h3 class="text-center" style="color: white">COM FRETE GRÁTIS</h3>

    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Inicio dos Produtos --><br/>

  <br/>
  <div class="container">
    <section id="content">
      <article class="item">
        <img src="./img/ovosbranco.jpg" height="130px" width="180px">
        <div class="tituloproduto">
          PLANO OVO VERMELHO MENSAL <br/> 1 ENTREGA COM 30 OVOS
        </div>
        <div class="descricaoproduto">
          <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; color: #ffcc00;"> R$ 19,99 </span> / ciclo
        </div>
        <div class="botaocomprar">
          <button type="submit" class="btn">VER TODOS OS PRODUTOS</button>
        </div>
      </article>

      <article class="item">
        <img src="./img/ovosbranco.jpg" height="130px" width="180px">
        <div class="tituloproduto">
          PLANO OVO VERMELHO MENSAL <br/> 1 ENTREGA COM 30 OVOS
        </div>
        <div class="descricaoproduto">
          <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; color: #ffcc00;"> R$ 19,99 </span> / ciclo
        </div>
        <div class="botaocomprar">
          <button type="submit" class="btn">VER TODOS OS PRODUTOS</button>
        </div>
      </article>

    </section>
  </div>


  <!-- FIM DOS PRODUTOS -->

  <div id="main_plans">

    <div class="content_plans">
      <span style="color: #ffcc00; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold">ENTREGA SEMANAL</span></br>
      <span style="color: white; font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold">OVOS NOVOS TODA SEMANA</span><br/>
      <span style="color: white;">Selecionamos todos os ovos com muito cuidado!<br/></span>
      <div class="botaocategorias">
        <button type="submit" class="btn">EU QUERO!</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content_plans">
      <span style="color: #ffcc00; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold"> ENTREGA QUINZENAL<br/></span>
      <span style="color: white; font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold">UMA ENTREGA A CADA 15 DIAS<br/></span>
      <span style="color: white;">Tudo acontece automaticamente, nem se preocupe!<br/></span>
      <div class="botaocategorias">
        <button type="submit" class="btn">EU QUERO!</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content_plans">
      <span style="color: #ffcc00; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold">ENTREGA MENSAL<br/></span>
      <span style="color: white; font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold">RECEBA UMA ENTREGA POR MÊS</span><br/>
      <span style="color: white;">Você ainda pode alterar seu plano quando quiser!</span><br/>
      <div class="botaocategorias">
        <button type="submit" class="btn">EU QUERO!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br/>


    <!-- Texto Index-->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col" id="textoindex">
          <h1 class=text-center>Reserve ovos pelo menor preço!</h1> <br/>
          <p class="text-center">Faça pacotes semanais, quinzenais ou mensais...</p>

          <p class=text-center>Vendemos para micro, média e grande empresas, e você pessoa física também pode adquirir!</p>

          <p class=text-center>Não espere o carro do ovo passar na sua rua, trabalahamos com atendimento 24 horas. 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Fim Texto Index -->
    <br>
    <hr>

    <?php 
include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifiquei o seu código HTML acima e há varias tags de fechamento inadequadas e fora de ordem, em seu menu por exemplo a tag `a` é aberta antes da tag `div` mas ao serem fechadas essa ordem se inverte.

```
<a href="index.php"><div class="menuitem"> Home <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a> </div>
```

Em outros momentos tags de fechamento de `div` são duplicadas, o problema relatado é uma consequência da página má estruturada.

Reestruture sua página edentando o código HTML, use quebra de linha para novas tags e tabs (espaçamentos) para iniciar o código após uma quebra de linha, por exemplo:

```
<nav id="main_menu">
    <a href="index.php">
        <div class="menuitem">
            Home
            <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="menuitem">
            Planos
            <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
        </div>
    </a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Agradeço o retorno, porém o erro acima era relacionado a configuração meta tag, já ajustei. Quando aos erros de estrutura irei me atentar. Obrigado!!